# Saving an entire form with vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am just starting with Vue and Vuex and am wondering how to go about saving an entire form to an API. I have found [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html) and it only seems like a good solution for a single field. Does this imply I would need to do a custom computed attribute with a getter and setter for each field in the form? I understand how data binding works well for local storage (which seems to be what most examples use) but updating a backend service with every keystroke seems like overkill.

What I would like to do is perform a single commit on a form when the user performs an action (like click a save button) and I feel like making a computed property or method for every field is not the right way to go.

Template:

```vue
<div v-show="isEditing" class="edit-view">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input :value="item.title" type="text" class="form-control" @input="update"  />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <input :value="item.description" type="text" class="form-control" @input="update" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```vue
export default {
  name: 'todo',
  props: ['item'],
  data() {
    return {
      isEditing: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showEdit() {
      this.isEditing = true;
    },
    update() {
      // Commit a change to vuex store
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the form data local to your form component. So define all form properties in `data()`. Apply `v-model` to all the input elements and your corresponding data properties. When user clicks submit, make a single commit with the form data.

This way, your form component will contain the edited values, and the vuex store will contain the submitted values.

Comment: How would you approach editing an entire form with pre-filled data from Vuex store?